# Order list of tuples based on a list of strings

Tags: python

I have two lists `order` and `data`. `order` is meant to be the order in which the list of tuple's in `data` should be.

```
# two lists
order = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'zip']
data = [(email, <object>), ('zip', <object>), ('name', <object>), ('phone', <object>)]

# what the result should be
[('name', <object>), ('email', <object>), ('phone', <object>), ('zip', <object>)]
```

I can't seem to develop a good algorithm for this. Closest I have gotten is:

```
result = [x for (x, y) in sorted(zip(data, order), key=lambda pair: pair[0])]
```

Which just orders everything in alphabetical order.

Any thoughts on a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to sort  on the first element of your data tuples based on its index in order:

```
order = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'zip']
data = [("email", "<object>"), ('zip', "<object>"), ('name', "<object>"), ('phone', "<object>")]

print sorted(data,key=lambda x:order.index(x[0]))
[('name', '<object>'), ('email', '<object>'), ('phone', '<object>'), ('zip', '<object>')]
```

You can sort in-place also:

```
data.sort(key=lambda x:order.index(x[0]))
print data
[('name', '<object>'), ('email', '<object>'), ('phone', '<object>'), ('zip', '<object>')]
```

This will also work if you have repeated elements:

```
data = [("email", "<object>"),("email", "<object>"), ('zip', "<object>"), ('name', "<object>"), ('phone', "<object>"),('name', "<object>")]
data.sort(key=lambda x:order.index(x[0]))
print data
[('name', '<object>'), ('name', '<object>'), ('email', '<object>'), ('email', '<object>'), ('phone', '<object>'), ('zip', '<object>')]
```

Comment: many good solutions, shows I need to dig into python more and better understand it, don't often need to do this. Went with this one because I understand it the best, and it is one line.

Comment: @percent, I added a way to sort the list in-place also.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a dictionary as an intermediary?

```
index = { t[0]: t for t in data }
result = [index[k] for k in order]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could turn `order` into a `dict`

```
>>> data = [('email', None), ('zip', None), ('name', None), ('phone', None)]
>>> order = {'name':0, 'email':1, 'phone':2, 'zip':3}
>>> sorted(data, key=lambda item : order[item[0]])
[('name', None), ('email', None), ('phone', None), ('zip', None)]
```

Comment: `index = {item: order.index(item) for item in order}` as a suggestion